# Run poetry-installed python scripts in optimized mode

Tags: python, assert, python-poetry

I have a `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.poetry.scripts]
# aka entry points or console scripts for setup.py users
merge = 'mypackage.__main__:main'
```

`mypackage` contains some `assert` statements that I do not want run in production, but I would like to run these scripts in ["optimized" mode](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-o).

Is this possible to do with a poetry script?

Comment: on which os are you?

Comment: mac OS and linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As related [on my ill-thought-out feature request for Poetry](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/3335), I should just be setting [`PYTHONOPTIMIZE=1`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONOPTIMIZE) for the user running these packages in production, which is functionally identical to calling the script with `-O`.

Answer (score 1):

When you install a package with a console entrypoint, `setuptools`' or `poetry`'s installer just creates a simple executable shim in the active python interpreter's `bin/`. The shim decides which python interpreter will be called to execute your package's code, and by extension also which flags accompany the call.

So, first of all you need to run `which merge` in order to find out where the shim lives. It should look similar to this, but the exact look is very os-dependent:

```py
#!/home/user/dev/merge/venv/bin/python3
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'mypackage','console_scripts','merge'
import re
import sys
...
```

Now just append  `-O` to the shebang, and you're done. I tested it on ubuntu and it worked just fine.

---

Caveats:

- shebangs only accept a single flag, so you better only need this one
- you need to re-add the flag after every single `poetry install`
- in a similar vein, you can't rig your `.wheel` to enforce this, in case you want to install this somewhere remote

Comment: +1 because it technically answers my question, but I do not think that this is a good production-ready solution so I did not accept the answer. I [made a feature request on poetry's github](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/3335) about this.

Comment: Fair enough, I'd also not want to deploy something like this. Something I was kind of hoping was that it'd make it possible for you to measure the impact of the flag, and that impact being too small to be worth the hassle ^^